# Why ES6 destructuring is needed in such as specific cases?

Tags: ecmascript-6

In a react+ES6 tutorial, i saw some usages of destructuring which look like the following and which i don't understand why they're needed:

```
updateFish = (key, updatedFish) => {
 const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
}
```

`this.state.fishes` is spread into a new object : `{}`
why not simply and directly do this ?

```
const fishes = this.state.fishes;
```

in another example, i think the reason would be to write a more concise code :

```
const updatedFish = {
...this.props.fish,
[event.currentTarrget.name]:event.currentTarget.value
}
```

but i guess if we would want more optimisation, i think this would be faster :

```
const updatedFish = this.props.fish;
updatedFish[event.currentTarrget.name] = event.currentTarget.value;
```

Comment: Because they presumably don't want to mutate the previous object, they want to create a shallow copy and change that.

Comment: as you can see it's an update function so presumably they would mutate the prev object indeed. but thanks anyway , now i learned for what it can useful :)